# Bind an application with public IP address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

I have an ASP.Net MVC application developed on my system. I want to access my site from remote computer by binding my app with public IP using following Commands,

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.42:3000/ user=everyone
```

in Visual Studio i have updated applicationhost.config file

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:3000:192.168.1.42" />
```

but it is still not working saying 
"Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

Comment: 503 is a server error, so if you're getting a response on that address it's binding properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In applicationhost.config file the localhost must be changed to your computer name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string GetIp()                      
 {
     string Ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ip))
     {
         Ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
     }
     return Ip;
 }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?